# Ao clicar no input, deslizar a tela para cima no react JS

Tags: javascript, react, input, rolamento, teclado

Olá gostaria de ajudar para quando eu clicar no input ele detect o teclado e deslizar a tela para cima deixando o input no topo da minha tela. Eu sei que no React Native tem essa seguinte biblioteca que detecta o teclado: `KeyboardAvoidingVie` porém eu gostária de saber se existe alguma biblioteca ou função javascript que realiaze essa questão de na hora que eu clicar no meu input ele deslize a tela para cima deixando o input no topo ou no local que eu quiser e ao sair do input ele volte ao normal.

Até o momento só achei a seguinte função que calcula o tamanho da minha tela:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function ScreenSize() {
const [windowDimenion, detectHW] = useState({
    winWidth: window.innerWidth,
    winHeight: window.innerHeight,
})

const detectSize = () => {
    detectHW({
        winWidth: window.innerWidth,
        winHeight: window.innerHeight,
    })
}

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', detectSize)

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', detectSize)
    }
}, [windowDimenion])

return (
    <div>
      <p>Width: <strong>{windowDimenion.winWidth} </strong></p>
      <p>Height: <strong>{windowDimenion.winHeight} </strong></p>
    </div>
)
```

}

inserir a descrição da imagem aqui
[Nesta imagem mostra como eu quero que o meu input fique após eu selecionar o meu input, o teclado tem que ocupar o espaço dele na tela deslizar o input para o topo ou deslizar o máximo que ele puder, desde de que ele fique acima do meu teclado.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQHGy.jpg)

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `ref` e o `scrollIntoView` para fazer a tela deslizar para cima quando o input é clicado. Exemplo de como fazer isso:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

function MyForm() {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    inputRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
      <form>
        <input ref={inputRef} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Ao clicar no botão, o input será rolado para o topo da tela de forma suave (`behavior: 'smooth'`). Se você quiser que o input fique em outra posição específica da tela, pode usar o `offsetTop` do elemento para determinar a posição em que ele deve ser rolado.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

function MyForm() {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    const inputPosition = inputRef.current.offsetTop;
    window.scrollTo({ top: inputPosition, behavior: 'smooth' });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
      <form>
        <input ref={inputRef} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```